# How to manually invoke a WiFi login splash window when already connected to WiFi?

Tags: macos, wifi

I'm using a hotel WiFi network after accepting some terms & conditions in a WiFi login splash window when first connected. The WiFi login window (in a Chrome browser) offered two choices - free (slow, apparently veryyy slow) and paid (presumably faster). I chose the free option. However, I now want to use the paid version, but I cannot invoke the login splash window again to make the selection. How can I do it manually, through browser or terminal?

I'm on Mac OS. Removing the WiFi network and reconnecting again does not help. I just have (slow) access to internet all the time and the login splash window never appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try releasing and [renewing your DHCP lease](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10743?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). If that doesn't work, you could try going to the page directly; sometimes it's located at [192.168.1.1](http://192.168.1.1:80), but you could go back in your history to find it.